# Eratosthenes sieve without multiply, divide, nor `for` loops

Tags: java, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

My friend and I are working on a university homework exercise to make an Eratosthenes-sieve without any multiplication, division nor `for` loops.
The problem is that I wrote it before our professor told us not to use those things and now I don't know what to do.
Changing the `for` loops to `while` loops is no big deal, but I have no clue how to get rid of the last multiplication at the end of the code.

My friend made some changes that I don't understand (I will comment the changes that he made) and I would be really thankful if someone could explain explain them to me.  In summary:

1. We need to get rid of the `for` loops and replace them with `while` loops
2. Get rid of the multiplication at the end of the code, which is my main problem.
3. Help to understand changes noted in comments.

Our code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class primesieb {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //so we declare values and used the scanner to make an input.
        int input = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("give an int bigger that 1:  ");
        input = in.nextInt();

        while (input <= 1)
        {
         //in case the number is smaller than 1.
                System.out.println("the Int must be bigger than 1!.");
                System.out.println("write an Int bigger than 1: ");
                input = in.nextInt(); 
        }
        in.close();
        //now first i wrote it without "+1" but my friend changed it to +1
           boolean[] x = new boolean[input + 1];
        //here I just wanted to add this to set that the position 0 in the string is not a prime number but after thinking I don't see its necessary

               x[0]=false;

        //he did write this commented for loop to assume that all of them are false but for me, it doesn't make sense, pls explain if it's necessary.
        //for (int i = 2; i < x.length; i++) {
          //  x[i] = false;}

        for (int i = 2; i < x.length; i++) {

            while (x[i]) 
            {
                i++;
            }
         // here how can we get rid of the multiplication.
        //the next for loop and if my friend did and a better explain would be nice helping me to represent my code better.
        for (int j = i; j*i < input; j++) 
            {
                x[i * j] = true;
            }
            if (! x[i] && i < input) 
            {
                System.out.println("the number" + i + "is prime. ");
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

We tested this code on Eclipse, and it worked, but we need to dodge the usage of multiplication.

Comment: Hint: A sequence like X, 2X, 3X etc. is the same as X, X+X, (X+X) +X...

Comment: @RealSkeptic. you are speaking about this part right??? 
**for (int j = i; j*i < input; j++)**
I couldn't agree more that mathematically that's 1000% true but I have no idea how to bring it in code.
sorry but my brain still doesn't get the whole coding logic. I'm a starter and I'm afraid that I have to ask you to explain to me how to write it in java.
thanks for trying to help me I appreciate it.

Comment: I tried now to use the (int)Math.sqrt(i) and I got an Error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
 at primesiebselber.main(primesiebselber.java:31)
I have no idea what is this. 
and i did try this   for (int j = i, z= (int)Math.pow (i,j); z < eingabe; j++) {
                x[z] = true; 
but the code is showing nothing after my input!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's simplify your number input:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int input = 0;

    while (input <= 1) {
        System.out.println("Give an int bigger than 1: ");
        input = in.nextInt();

        if (input <= 1) {
            System.out.println("The int must be bigger than 1!.");
        }
    }

    in.close();
```

Minimizing use of space, your friend wasn't correct about:

```
//now first i wrote it without "+1" but my friend changed it to +1
boolean[] x = new boolean[input + 1];

x[0]=false;
```

Since you're only printing primes less than `input` (even if `input` is a prime) and you're skipping over 0 and 1, you can make `x` three elements shorter:

```
boolean x[] = new boolean[input - 2];  // all initialized to false
```

Any `for` loop can always be unwound to a `while` loop:

```
for (int i = 2; i < x.length; i++) {
```

Of the three semi-colon separated elements in the `for` loop setup, the first comes before the `while` loop, the second is the `while` loop condition and the third is the last statement in the `while` loop:

```
int i = 2;

while (i < input) {  // 'input' instead of 'x.length' in our new design

    // (the rest of the code that follows below goes here)

    i++;
}
```

This is a potential problem:

```
while (x[i]) 
{
    i++;
}
```

As there is no bounds check on `i` before the next `x[i]`.  This worked for you earlier because of the extra unused space allocated in `x`.  Now we need to be more precise:

```
while (x[i - 2]) {
    if (++i >= input) {
        break outer;
    }
}
```

We're using `i - 2` as we're skipping over the missing 0 & 1 entries.  We're using `break outer;` instead of just `break;` as we need to get out of the `while` loop that encloses this `while` loop.  So go back and change:

```
while (i < input) {
```

above to instead be:

```
 outer: while (i < input) {
```

The conversion of this `for` loop is somewhat different due to its undesired multiplication:

```
for (int j = i; j*i < input; j++) {
    x[i * j] = true;
}
```

We're going to repeatedly add `i` instead of multiply by `i`.  It's slightly less efficient at the start but otherwise fine:

```
int j = i + i;

while (j < input) {
    x[j - 2] = true;
    j += i;
}
```

This test is not needed:

```
if (! x[i] && i < input)
```

As we already know `x[i]` is `false` and `i < input` from our work above.  So just finish up with:

```
System.out.println("The number " + i + " is prime.");

i++;  // we added this earlier to finish off our first 'for' to 'while' conversion
```

If you follow these changes carefully, you should now have a working program that has no `for` loops, no multiplication, and no wasted array elements.